# I am getting error when using nix build command

Tags: plutus, nix

when using following command

`nix --extra-experimental-features nix-command build -f default.nix plutus.haskell.pack ages.plutus-core.components.library`

getting following error

`error: could not set permissions on '/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user' to 755: Operation not permitted`

to solve this I used sudo

```
sudo nix --extra-experimental-features nix-command build -f default.nix plutus.haskell packages.plutus-core.components.library
```

but then getting another error

```
sudo: nix: command not found
```

I am following [evernote.com](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s426/client/snv?noteGuid=b34acc67-c94b-fc64-9350-398a8f6fc6ec&noteKey=7e6b84c9501e9949eef2cadf6e35eaff&sn=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.evernote.com%2Fshard%2Fs426%2Fsh%2Fb34acc67-c94b-fc64-9350-398a8f6fc6ec%2F7e6b84c9501e9949eef2cadf6e35eaff&title=Installation) for the installation process.